# Transposing JSONB Array Elements - Postgres 11.5?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a table the structure is defined as below

```
CREATE TABLE logs (
    logid uuid NOT NULL,
    logjson jsonb NOT NULL,
    createdtime timestamp NOT NULL
);
```

The sample JSONB string is shown below

```
{
    "RouteId": "353f89f5-b414-40cd-bd19-20378d51e723",
    "RouteName": "GetPickCompleteMessages",
    "CustomLinks": {
    },
    "MachineName": "12ws3",
    "DataBaseTimings": [
        {
            "ApiMethod": null,
            "ExecuteType": "OpenAsync",
            "CommandString": "Connection OpenAsync()",
            "DurationMilliseconds": 1138.5,
        },
        {
            "ApiMethod": null,
            "ExecuteType": "Reader",
            "CommandString": "GetPckg",
            "DurationMilliseconds": 124.5,
        },
            {
            "ApiMethod": null,
            "ExecuteType": "Close",
            "CommandString": "Connection Close()",
            "DurationMilliseconds": 27.9,
        }

    ],
    "DurationMilliseconds": 1546.2
}
```

I am looking for an output in this manner

```
| RouteName                 | OpenAsyncTime | ReaderTime | CloseTime | TotalDuration |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| GetPickCompleteMessages   |    1138.5     | 124.5      | 27.9      |  1546.2       |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any pointers on this is greatly appreciated.

Also how do I extend the solution if there were multiple arrays. By multiple arrays this is what I mean

```
{
    "RouteId": "353f89f5-b414-40cd-bd19-20378d51e723",
    "RouteName": "GetPickCompleteMessages",
    "CustomLinks": {
    },
    "MachineName": "12ws3",
    "ChildProfiles": [
        {
            "ApiMethod": "PublishShipViaRequestToQueue",
            "DurationMilliseconds": 0.1,
        }
    ],
    "DataBaseTimings": [
        {
            "ApiMethod": null,
            "ExecuteType": "OpenAsync",
            "CommandString": "Connection OpenAsync()",
            "DurationMilliseconds": 1138.5,
        },
        {
            "ApiMethod": null,
            "ExecuteType": "Reader",
            "CommandString": "GetPckg",
            "DurationMilliseconds": 124.5,
        },
            {
            "ApiMethod": null,
            "ExecuteType": "Close",
            "CommandString": "Connection Close()",
            "DurationMilliseconds": 27.9,
        }

    ],
    "DurationMilliseconds": 1546.3
}
```

The output needs to be in this fashion

```
| RouteName                          | PublishShipViaRequestToQueueTime | OpenAsyncTime | ReaderTime | CloseTime | TotalDuration |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| GenerateRequestAndPublishToQueue   |    0.1                           | 1138.5        | 124.5       | 27.9      |  1546.3       |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Thanking you in advance

Comment: What does `CONSTRAINT logs_pkey null` mean?

Comment: It's always those three entries in the array, in this exact order, right? Otherwise the output wouldn't be possible.

Comment: There could be multiple entries in the array, I am only interested in those three

Comment: This would be a bit shorter with Postgres 12: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=48ca68700c62f9c131f94621c571b32c

Answer (score 0):

I think a few json accesses should do it:

```
SELECT
   logjson -> 'RouteName' AS "RouteName",
   logjson -> 'DataBaseTimings' -> 0 -> 'DurationMilliseconds' AS "OpenAsyncTime",
   logjson -> 'DataBaseTimings' -> 1 -> 'DurationMilliseconds' AS "ReaderTime",
   logjson -> 'DataBaseTimings' -> 2 -> 'DurationMilliseconds' AS "CloseTime",
   logjson -> 'DurationMilliseconds' AS "TotalDuration"
FROM
   logs
```

If that doesn't cut it because the indices are not known, you'd have to do subqueries on the json array:

```
SELECT
   logjson -> 'RouteName' AS "RouteName",
   (SELECT el -> 'DurationMilliseconds'
       FROM jsonb_array_elements(logjson -> 'DataBaseTimings') el
       WHERE el ->> 'ExecuteType' = 'OpenAsync'
   ) AS "OpenAsyncTime",
   (SELECT el -> 'DurationMilliseconds'
       FROM jsonb_array_elements(logjson -> 'DataBaseTimings') el
       WHERE el ->> 'ExecuteType' = 'Reader'
   ) AS "ReaderTime",
   (SELECT el -> 'DurationMilliseconds'
       FROM jsonb_array_elements(logjson -> 'DataBaseTimings') el
       WHERE el ->> 'ExecuteType' = 'Close'
   ) AS "CloseTime",
   logjson -> 'DurationMilliseconds' AS "TotalDuration"
FROM
   logs
```

Or do it the fancy way and use

```
SELECT
   logjson -> 'RouteName' AS "RouteName",
   typed_values -> 'OpenAsync' AS "OpenAsyncTime",
   typed_values -> 'Reader' AS "ReaderTime",
   typed_values -> 'Close' AS "CloseTime",
   logjson -> 'DurationMilliseconds' AS "TotalDuration"
FROM
   logs,
   LATERAL (
       SELECT jsonb_object_agg(el ->> 'ExecuteType', el -> 'DurationMilliseconds') AS typed_values
       FROM jsonb_array_elements(logjson -> 'DataBaseTimings') el
   ) AS t
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion... So in reality there could more array elements, but I am only interested in these three ExecuteTypes.. So the array position can vary

Comment: @TheVMan Is it guaranteed that there is only one entry per `ExecuteType`?

Comment: For the time being it is only one. I tried to execute the statement and received this error SQL Error [22023]: ERROR: cannot extract elements from a scalar
  ERROR: cannot extract elements from a scalar
  ERROR: cannot extract elements from a scalar

Comment: @TheVMan [worksforme](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=eb0f73d1719ba8613c1b73f24b8e7ff8). The error message sounds like `logjson -> 'DataBaseTimings'` doesn't have the expected results.

Comment: Thanks i guess that was the issue. Is there a way to check for the existence of these three elements, that we only take into consideration of the ones that has these three array elements. Once again thanks for all the help

Comment: @TheVMan [works fine for me](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=41b595b7cfacfee149139c953ba15501) even when omitting a value - the column ends up with `null` as expected. Can you make a [mcve] in the fiddle please?

Comment: I was able to work around by creating different functions for the various possibilities and then creating a wrapper function that identifies which one to call.

Comment: Your solution works fine.. There is one more help that i need. I have updated the main question with the same.

Comment: @TheVMan Just do the same to access that - either another subselect or lateral join. Just get the elements from the `logjson -> 'ChildProfiles'` this time, and filter by the `el -> 'ApiMethod'` instead of the `ExecuteType`.

Comment: you can try to mark the answer if it helped @TheVMan